# Isosceles right angle triangle in a circle (Verification)

Tags: geometry, proof-verification

This is s a question for a big test and I want to make sure that not only am I answering it correctly, but I am doing it the best way.

"An isosceles right triangle is inscribed in a circle. The radius is 4 units. What is the product of the area and perimeter?"

I started by finding d(diameter)=2r=8, because this would be the hypotenuse.

Then I divided by √2 and ended up with the leg being 4√2.

The perimeter then is just 2(4√2)+8=8√2+8

Then (4√2)² is 32.

So 32(8√2+8) is 256√2+256.

After doing this I checked the answer key and it showed to correct answer as 128√2+512.

Where did I go wrong or is the Key wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The area should be $\frac{(4\sqrt2)^2}{2}=16$ and so the answer should be $128\sqrt2+128$. And yes, it looks like your answer key is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You squared the length of one of the legs for the area of the triangle. You want half that amount for a triangle. It still gives a different answer than the key.